# launch node.js on osx without terminal

Tags: macos, node.js, terminal

looking to launch node.js on startup (and hidden) without having to open terminal.

currently, i have to open terminal - change directory to where my script file is with:

```
 cd web/
```

then open my script file in node.js with

```
 node bridge.js
```

this can be clunky to have to go through every time, plus if i close the terminal window, the script stops.

would be ideal to have a script (applescript or other) to open this script and run continuously in the background.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into node-mac module https://github.com/coreybutler/node-mac

I myself have never used this but from the description, it looks like that's what you need.